# How do I set where different incoming emails go in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I would like emails from different addresses to go to different folders in Thunderbird. Is there a way of doing this? For example, I have set up a folder for emails from Wikia forums (email address: community@wikia.com) and if you'd like to give me an example of how to do any of your instructions this folder might be a good place to start (it's actually a subfolder under 'Wikia' that is called 'Forums'). For me I generally find that examples do help me understand what people mean, so they would be appreciated if possible. If it is relevant I am running Thunderbird on 64 bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message filters. Add a filter with the rule:

From || Contains || filteredaddress@foo.bar

Performs action:

Move Message To || Foobar folder

For multiple addresses, add as many of the matching rules as you want, and select "match any of the following."